# Android / Execution failed for task checkDebugAarMetadata / A failure occurred while executing CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, aar, maven-publish

*TL'DR:* In [this Android Kotlin library](https://github.com/Umweltzone/roadsigns) I [updated from Gradle 5.6.4 to 6.6.1](https://github.com/Umweltzone/roadsigns/commit/d5d8d24fab772e486b222e6c747df203a02986b5) (commit `d5d8d2`). Now I cannot build a project depending on the aar anymore.

## Test setup

I build and deploy the *aar* to *mavenLocal* ...

```
$ ./gradlew clean :roadsigns:assemble
$ ./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
```

... and then reference the deployed library artifact in the sample Android `app` module. First I add `mavenLocal()` in the root *build.gradle* file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal() // <-- Add this
    }
}
```

I reference the `mavenLocal()` dependency directly:

```
dependencies {
    implementation
    // implementation project(":roadsigns")
    implementation "info.metadude.kotlin.library.roadsigns:roadsigns:$version"
    implementation Libs.kotlinStdlib
    // ...
```

## The error

When I build the sample app then I get the following **build error**:

```
$ ./gradlew clean assembleDebug

Execution failed for task ':checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > A dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) does
        not specify an aarFormatVersion value, which is a required value.
        Dependency: info.metadude.kotlin.library.roadsigns:roadsigns:4.0.0.
        AAR metadata file: /home/USERNAME/.m2/repository/info/metadude/kotlin/library/roadsigns/roadsigns/4.0.0/roadsigns-4.0.0-javadoc.jar.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > A dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) does
        not specify an aarFormatVersion value, which is a required value.
        Dependency: info.metadude.kotlin.library.roadsigns:roadsigns:4.0.0.
        AAR metadata file: /home/USERNAME/.m2/repository/info/metadude/kotlin/library/roadsigns/roadsigns/4.0.0/roadsigns-4.0.0-sources.jar.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > A dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) does
        not specify an aarFormatVersion value, which is a required value.
        Dependency: info.metadude.kotlin.library.roadsigns:roadsigns:4.0.0.
        AAR metadata file: /home/USERNAME/.m2/repository/info/metadude/kotlin/library/roadsigns/roadsigns/4.0.0/roadsigns-4.0.0.aar.
```

## Context information

When I try the same with Gradle 5.6.4 then there is **no error**.

In the Android Kotlin library I am using:

- [digital.wup:android-maven-publish:3.6.3](https://github.com/wupdigital/android-maven-publish)
- [com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin)

I using *Java 8 (OpenJDK)* on my machine and verified that the same error occurs on a different computer.

## Experiments

- When I deploy the library with Gradle 5 and build the app with Gradle 5 or Gradle 6 in both cases it works.

## The question

What changed from Gradle 5 to Gradle 6 which causes the *aar* to be broken (?)

## Findings

- I took a look at the files being deployed in `mavenLocal()`:

  ~/.m2/repository/info/metadude/kotlin/library/roadsigns
  └── roadsigns
  ├── 4.0.0
  │   ├── roadsigns-4.0.0.aar
  │   ├── roadsigns-4.0.0-javadoc.jar
  │   ├── roadsigns-4.0.0.module
  │   ├── roadsigns-4.0.0.pom
  │   └── roadsigns-4.0.0-sources.jar
  └── maven-metadata-local.xml
- I compared the files deployed with Gradle 5 and Gradle 6. Interestingly, the `roadsigns-4.0.0.aar` files are binary equivalent. The `pom` file differs, though:

  [image: Diff of roadsigns-4.0.0.pom files]
- Also there is a `roadsigns-4.0.0.module` file only when I deploy with Gradle 6.
- When I **manually** remove the "new" `do_not_remove: published-with-gradle-metadata` part from the file deployed with Gradle 6 then the app builds **successfully**! The question remains ... what's going on here?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem very likely comes from the plugins you are using to publish the library (`digital.wup:android-maven-publish:3.6.3`) and the quite abandoned bintray Gradle plugin which hasn't been updated to support Gradle metadata.

I bet the `.module` file that takes precedence over the content of the `pom.xml` files in Gradle 6 consumer projects is improperly populated because of how these two plugins work.

Fortunately, there's now built-in `maven-publish` support in the Android Gradle Plugin (so first-party), and it's documented here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin

With it, you can publish to mavenLocal, bintray, and any other proper maven repo.

You should not have any issues if you use that instead of any third party alternatives.

Comment: Thank you, that was my [suspicion](https://github.com/wupdigital/android-maven-publish/pull/43), too. I managed to [migrate](https://github.com/Umweltzone/roadsigns/pull/22) the project now.

Answer (score 11):

I was running into a lot of these errors:

```
...
The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\CUR_USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4e8a32482e233cfbbc450e03aabed8dd\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
...
```

What I did to fix it was

- open `build.gradle` (app)
- change android . `compileSdk` to 31 from 30
- change android . defaultConfig . `targetSdk` to 31 from 30
- File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

- You may need to tailor the values for your respective Sdk levels (currently working 34).

Comment: I had different dependencies and was facing the same issue. Upgrading compileSdk to 31 helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. I found a temporary solution:
Add the `aar` suffix to the error module and make it transitive (or you will lose dependencies) e.g.:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
```

reports "not specify an aarFormatVersion" error, compilation failed.

change to:

```
implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0@aar") {
    transitive = true
}
```

compile error disappeared.

AS [Louis CAD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4433326/louis-cad) says, you can use built-in 'maven-publish' to solve this issues.

Comment: Yes, the workaround works. Thank you. Nevertheless, I want to understand why it stopped working as it did with the former Gradle version.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is download the library package, copy LICENSE and other files to
src/main-> new "Java Resources Folder"  -> new "META-INF" folder

```
implementation 'org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:1.2.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is due to this
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'

change version ktx: 1.9.0 to 1.7.0
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'