# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. When i try to run my program in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this message

```
> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\Svit\AndroidStudioProjects\DoTask

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.recyclerview:recylerview:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/recyclerview/recylerview/1.1.0/recylerview-1.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/recyclerview/recylerview/1.1.0/recylerview-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

I got this when I tried to run my program for a to-do list. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android / Execution failed for task checkDebugAarMetadata / A failure occurred while executing CheckAarMetadataWorkAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64945616/android-execution-failed-for-task-checkdebugaarmetadata-a-failure-occurred-w)